# Capturing new HTTP calls

Tags: windows, command-line, url, command-line-arguments

I would like to capture system calls to open (http) urls.  I'm not concerned with what the browser is doing internally.  Rather, what URLs are attempted to be opened by explorer, or other programs (installers, particularly).

I can establish a "graburl.bat" file:

```
@echo off
echo Param is: "%1"
pause
```

as the default HTTP handler by setting `c:\graburl.bat" %1` (or `"c:\graburl.bat" "%1"`) in the registry (several locations/methods will work, but currently, I'm using 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command').  However, I can't seem to capture complete URLs that contain ampersand (&).

For example, with my test setup above, running

```
start "https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=escape+ampersand"
```

opens a window with:

```
Param is: ""http://www.google.com/search?client=opera
'q' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't have any way of escaping (with ^) or encoding the called URL, so I'm not sure what I can do.  Is there some way to modify the parameter on the fly?

Obviously, browsers work with complicated URLs because their http handling calls are just `"browser.exe" %1`.  I also tried using `"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /k echo %1` but that too fails.

Any suggestions?  I'd prefer a "native" way, but a small, third-party, preferably OSS program would be OK too.  Eventually, I want to put these into a log, not just echo them to the screen, so a cmdline .exe that accepts a string argument and pushes it out to a file would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Asking for direction to a program is explicitly off-topic here and will most likely lead to your question being closed. My advice is to edit it out of your question.

Comment: Can you quote the command line in your HTTP handler: `c:\graburl.bat "%1"`?

Comment: @Xavierjazz Sorry, I'm new here and not clear on your meaning. Do you mean asking about the bat file code is off-topic, or asking which program would work is off topic?  I'm not sure where my question fits as it may or may not be a programming solution.

Comment: @heavyd The .bat code is the content of "graburl.bat".

Comment: @Xavierjazz Please read the discussion here: http://meta.superuser.com/q/7736/820

Comment: @Teknowledgist yes, but you've setup the .bat file to run when you open a URL, when you set that up you should quote the parameter.  I think you can edit this in the registry.

Comment: @heavyd Thanks for the response.  I am using the registry, and I have tried all kinds of quote combinations.  I have edited the OP to clarify a bit.

Comment: You already know you're getting the whole string in the batch. Your problem is that the ampersand gets interpreted. Maybe check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107975/escape-ampersands-in-variables-win-batch) which might have a solution. What did you setup in the registry? If you are already calling the script using something like `my.bat "<url>"` you'd run `echo ""<url>""` which would mean you'd have one set of `"` too much.